# Change style programmatically from css-file without using .css()

Tags: jquery, css

I have css-file with next styles:

```
.myClass {
...
}

.myClass:focus {
...
}
```

Is it possible to change style from that file from code? For example I need to set focused style to input element when I press button. Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class in .css file and change the old class to the new one using jQuery.

You can set the class (regardless of what it was) by using .attr(), like this:

```
 $("#td_id").attr('class', 'newClass');
```

If you want to add a class, use .addclass() instead, like this:

```
 $("#td_id").addClass('newClass');
```

Or a short way to swap classes using .toggleClass():

```
 $("#td_id").toggleClass('change_me newClass');
```